# Inline block elements not lining up horizontally side by side

Tags: html, css

I'm not quite why the two blocks below (section.structure and section.specificity) are not lining up. When I reduce the width (past a certain number, not sure exactly what number this is) they line up.

I need the width around 500px (or each block taking up approximately half the width of the screen) but when I do this they stack on top of each other. Any ideas?

**HTML**

```
<main>
      <section class= "structure">

      </section>

      <section class= "specificity">

      </section>
```

**CSS**

```
section.structure {
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 10px;
    border: rgb(245,245, 245);
    display: inline-block;
}

section.specificity {
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 10px;
    border: rgb(245,245, 245);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Changing width measurements, vertical-align. No change.

Comment: Would you provide a demo?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not restricted to using `display: inline-block` you can use flexbox.
If you need to create space between the two elements you can use the `gap` property. Also I'd advise against setting fixed `height` and `width` in pixels as you can have problems with the layout being responsive
HTML:

```css
main {
  display: flex;
}

section {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<main>
 <section class="structure">hi</section>
  <section class="specificity">hello</section>
</main>
```

Comment: I've tried putting this in, I can now get the elements side by side - but they don't fill approx half the page each

Comment: Send me the jsfiddle of your code, I'll see what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? It also uses flexbox like the previous answer. I use https://suiq.jp/flex-layout-generator/ for reference.

```css
main {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

section.structure {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 10px;
  border: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}

section.specificity {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
  border: rgb(245, 245, 245);
}

section {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="structure">
    test
  </section>

  <section class="specificity">
    test
  </section>
</main>
```